# Vim: How do you get the change list in script?

Tags: vim, vimscript

I know that you can print the changelist by running `:changes`.  Is there a way to get this information in vimscript?  Even by parsing the print somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:redir` command to redirect command-line output to a register, a file, or a variable. To capture the output of `:changes` in register `a`, execute the following.

```
:set nomore
:redir @a
:changes
:redir END
:set more
```

See

```
:help :redir
:help 'more'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture the raw output of any Ex command with `:redir`:

```
redir => mychanges
changes
redir END
```

`mychanges` is a `string` that you manipulate like any other string.